# How to select MYSQL Content with between Date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I display values from the database of the Stand column with the help of the Datum column between two dates?

I tried the following code, but no result:

```
$sqlAverage10 = "SELECT Stand FROM Aktienstand WHERE Symbol=:symbol AND Datum BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate10";
                    if ($stmtAverage10 = $pdo->prepare($sqlAverage10)) {
                        $stmtAverage10->execute(array(

                            ':symbol' => $kurs['Symbol'],
                            ':startDate' => $startDate,
                            ':endDate10' => $endDate10
                        ));
                        //var_dump($kurs['Datum']);
                        //var_dump ($stmtAverage10);
                        //echo ($startDate = $kurs['Datum']);
                        $stmtAverage10New = $stmtAverage10->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

> :symbol = test
> :startDate = 2021-10-09
> :endDate = 2021-09-29

My table for e.g.:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/abEta.png

Comment: if the column Datum from type **DATE** ??

Answer (score 0):

That should work as long as your column is a `date` or `datetime` column.

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution!

Comment: Could you post the solution to help any other users that might find this question

Comment: My problem is that if the earliest specified date does not exist, only one value is selected. Do you have any ideas on this?
SELECT Stand FROM Aktienstand WHERE Symbol=:symbol AND Datum BETWEEN :endDate10 AND :startDate